# Managing Abstract subclass within a generic List in Java

Tags: java, class, generics, abstract

Generics and abstracts are mind boggling difficult to deal with, so bear with me while I try my best to explain the problem in a simple manner.

I have the following classes:

```
public class Community<T extends Person> {
    List<T> people;

    public void add(T person) {
        people.add(person);
    }

    public List<T> getPeople() {
        return people;
    }
}

public abstract class Person {}

public class Aussie extends Person {}
```

Here is the code to instantiate a community of Aussies:

```
Aussie aus1 = new Aussie();
Aussie aus2 = new Aussie();

Community<Aussie> aussieCommunity = new Community<>();
aussieCommunity.add(aus1);
aussieCommunity.add(aus2);
```

Now let's take a step further and say that I have multiple communities that I wish to systematically store inside a list as follow:

```
List<Community<?>> communities;
```

I hope you're still with me because here is my problem:

I need to write a code that will take the list of community and display each person's details - assuming each person's details will be accessed differently in their own class. Example: Aussie may say "Oi" as hi, American's may say "Hello" as hi.

```
for (Community<?> community : communities) {
    // I don't know what the type of community this is so, I use wildcard:
    List<? extends Person> people = community.getPeople();
    for (Type person : people) { // How do I specify the type of person eg Aussie/American etc here?
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Any suggestion on how I can specify the type of person in the second for loop?

Comment: Why you don't use an abstract method in Person ?

Comment: Agree with Mailkov. Put an abstract method in Person and override it in all subclasses. Then you dont need to know what kind of person it is in the loop. inheritance will solve the problem for you.

Comment: `people.add(person);` in `Community#getPeople` will give you an error.

Comment: Iterate over Person Class and check if it is an instanceOf Aussie or American and specify your condition in if loop.

Comment: @JonnyHenly That's in `Community#add` and it doesn't give a compile error. It will only give in error if there was code that tried to call `Community#add` on a `Community<?>` but the OP didn't post any code that does that.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt look at the revisions to the OP's question located [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27100474/revisions)

Comment: Well... that was simpler than I thought :) I like Navish's suggestion as it allows me to avoid abstract method in case I need to do something unique only to a specific class... eg animeAussieBoxingAKangeroo() haha

Comment: I don't quite understand why this question is being upvoted.

Comment: @VictorWong to you it may look simple, but to someone like me I would find this question useful. Anyway, I do concede it is simple now that I've been provided the answer in the comment. Though to leave it on or flag it for deletion? Suggestion?

Comment: @user3804927 seriously not the issue of simple or not, but a very common one that you can easily search for a solution. I just feel amazed that this is being upvoted, no offence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Here is an small example of how it can be done:

```
public abstract class Person {
    public final String say(String sentance) {
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(sentance);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String word = tokenizer.nextToken();
            String slang = getSlang(word);
            sb.append(slang != null ? slang : word);
            sb.append(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens() ? " " : "");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private String getSlang(String word) {
        return getSlangMap().get(word);
    }

    protected abstract Map<String, String> getSlangMap();
}


public class Aussi extends Person {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getSlangMap() {
        Map<String, String> slangMap = new HashMap<>();
        slangMap.put("hi", "Oi");
        slangMap.put("there", "theeer");
        return slangMap;
    }
}

public class Swede extends Person {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getSlangMap() {
        Map<String, String> slangMap = new HashMap<>();
        slangMap.put("hi", "hejsan");
        slangMap.put("there", "där");
        return slangMap;
    }
}

public class CommunityTest {
    @Test
    public void testSayHiThere() throws Exception {
        Aussi au1 = new Aussi();
        Aussi au2 = new Aussi();
        Community<Aussi> aussiCommunity = new Community<>();
        aussiCommunity.add(au1);
        aussiCommunity.add(au2);

        Swede sw1 = new Swede();
        Swede sw2 = new Swede();
        Community<Swede> swedeCommunity = new Community<>();
        swedeCommunity.add(sw1);
        swedeCommunity.add(sw2);

        List<Community<? extends Person>> communities = new ArrayList<>();
        communities.add(aussiCommunity);
        communities.add(swedeCommunity);

        for (Community<? extends Person> community : communities) {
            for (Person person : community.getPeople()) {
                System.out.println(person.say("hi there"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```